# How to get rid of gaps in footer, There's white gaps under there?

Tags: html, css

my website: https://www.nearestbusiness.com  Nearest Business

please help me sir

I thank you in advance

````
```
#footer-copyright{
    background:#242634;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    color:#aaa;
    padding:20px 0
}
 #footer-copyright > .container{
    margin:0 auto
}
 #social-footer{
    float:right
}
 #social-footer .widget{
    line-height:30px
}
 .social-footer ul{
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block
}
 .social-footer ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 0 0 14px
}
 .social-footer ul li a{
    font-size:16px;
    color:#aaa;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    padding:0 3px;
    transition:color .17s ease
}
 .social-footer ul li:last-child a{
    padding-right:0
}
 .social-footer ul li a:hover{
    color:$(main.color)
}
 #footer-copyright .copyright-area{
float:left;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:30px;
}
 #footer-copyright .copyright-area a{
    color:$(main.color)
}
 #footer-copyright .copyright-area a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline
```
````

Comment: Your website has lots of error in the chrome console, this might be the issue. It completely crash when I inspect your website and scroll

Comment: So you mean the occurrence of the debugger on my website affects the gap in the footer

Comment: But those white gaps in the footer sometimes disappear when I refresh the page?

Comment: I might stop the loading of element on your page which could be creating this white gap. There's hundreds of console errors on your website.

Comment: I ask for help sir. I'm just a beginner who wants to keep learning

Is that console error showing up from the javascript and css I'm using?

Comment: Yes, there is some javascript errors in the console. Yo can do a right click on your page in Chrome, click on `inspect` and then click on `console` to see all the errors